# best way to write dictionary data into csv or excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write dictionary data into csv file.

Keys:

```
['file_name', 'candidate_skills', 'SF_name', 'RB_name', 'mb_number', 'email']
```

Dictionary

```
{'file_name': 'Aarti Banarashi.docx', 'candidate_skills': ['JQuery', ' ', 'Bootstrap', 'codeigniter', '\n', 'Javascript', 'Analysis', 'Ajax', 'HTML', 'Html5', 'SQL', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'CSS'], 'SF_name': None, 'RB_name': 'aarti banarashi\t\t\t', 'mb_number': ['+918108493333'], 'email': 'aartisingh271294@gmail.com'}
```

I was thinking each dictionary will be written in on row with each value in new column

```
'file_name'  'candidate_skills'  'SF_name'   'RB_name'   'mb_number'     'email'
```

I am getting results like this, into single column only:

```
file_name,Aarti Banarashi.docx
candidate_skills,"['JQuery', ' ', 'Bootstrap', 'codeigniter', '\n', 'Javascript', 'Analysis', 'Ajax', 'HTML', 'Html5', 'SQL', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'CSS']"
SF_name,
RB_name,aarti banarashi
mb_number,['+918108493333']
email,aartisingh271294@gmail.com
```

Can you please help me to write it in correct manner? Also when I add new records, it should get appended

My code:

```
with open('dict.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in res.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Expected output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yuSR.png)

Comment: If you're writing a dictionary to a CSV file, use [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). Currently you're explicitly writing each key-value pair to its own row (`writer.writerow([key, value])`), so it's unclear why that being the outcome was surprising to you.

Comment: Code is unreadable in comments, particularly in Python where whitespace matters. **[Edit] the question**, to give a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, I tried `writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, res.keys())` which gives me error `ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Aarti Yadav.docx'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you work with tables I recommend pandas.

Here is the pandas solution:

```
d = {'file_name': 'Aarti Banarashi.docx', 'candidate_skills': ['JQuery', ' ', 'Bootstrap', 'codeigniter', '\n', 'Javascript', 'Analysis', 'Ajax', 'HTML', 'Html5', 'SQL', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'CSS'], 'SF_name': None, 'RB_name': 'aarti banarashi\t\t\t', 'mb_number': ['+918108493333'], 'email': 'aartisingh271294@gmail.com'}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

Output:

```
file_name,candidate_skills,SF_name,RB_name,mb_number,email
Aarti Banarashi.docx,"['JQuery', ' ', 'Bootstrap', 'codeigniter', '\n', 'Javascript', 'Analysis', 'Ajax', 'HTML', 'Html5', 'SQL', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'CSS']",,aarti banarashi          ,['+918108493333'],aartisingh271294@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script was iterating over each key value pair in your dictionary and then calling `writerow()` for each pair. `writerow()` will give you a single new row, so calling it multiple time in this way will give you one row per pair.

`res` only contains data for a single row in your CSV file. Using a `csv.DictWriter()`, a single call to `writerow()` will convert all the dictionary entries into a single output row:

```
import csv

res = {'file_name': 'Aarti Banarashi.docx', 'candidate_skills': ['JQuery', ' ', 'Bootstrap', 'codeigniter', '\n', 'Javascript', 'Analysis', 'Ajax', 'HTML', 'Html5', 'SQL', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'CSS'], 'SF_name': None, 'RB_name': 'aarti banarashi\t\t\t', 'mb_number': ['+918108493333'], 'email': 'aartisingh271294@gmail.com'}
fieldnames = ['file_name', 'candidate_skills', 'SF_name', 'RB_name', 'mb_number', 'email']

with open('dict.csv', 'wb') as f_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerow(res)
```

Giving you an output `dict.csv` file as:

```
file_name,candidate_skills,SF_name,RB_name,mb_number,email
Aarti Banarashi.docx,"['JQuery', ' ', 'Bootstrap', 'codeigniter', '\n', 'Javascript', 'Analysis', 'Ajax', 'HTML', 'Html5', 'SQL', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'CSS']",,aarti banarashi          ,['+918108493333'],aartisingh271294@gmail.com
```

By explicitly passing `fieldnames` is forces the ordering of the columns in the output to what you provide. If the ordering is not important, and you can instead use `fieldnames=res.keys()`